# Cannot connect to windows server with Domain Account using Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

I've followed this [guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#active-directory-support) to setup Ansible for use it with Windows Server.

But when I try to connect I obtain an error. The user used is Domain Administrator and has permissions to connect to that remote server.

> $ klist

> Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000

> Default principal: lrossi@TOPTIERRA.IT

> Valid starting       Expires              Service principal

> 07/29/2016 17:30:56  07/30/2016 03:30:56  krbtgt/TOPTIERRA.IT@TOPTIERRA.IT
> renew until 08/05/2016 17:30:50

> $ ansible -m setup web -u lrossi@TOPTIERRA.IT

> trr-pp-wa1 | UNREACHABLE! => {

> "changed": false,

> "msg": "ssl: 401 Unauthorized.",

> "unreachable": true

> }

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

Assuming you're using the latest pywinrm (0.2.0), did you install with the kerberos option (eg `pip install pywinrm[kerberos]`)?

Also, if that doesn't cover it, try adding `ansible_winrm_transport=kerberos` to your inventory vars for that host. Newer versions are less forceful about assuming a particular authtype from the username (to allow for use of LiveID, etc).

Comment: Thanks Matt! Works fine with `ansible_winrm_transport=kerberos`. I've installed also `pip install kerberos` and `pip install requests_kerberos`

Comment: Followed advice from both of you, here on the other side of the covid pandemic.. and it solved a different error: `ntlm: the specified credentials were rejected by the server`. I had seen it so many times I was starting to believe it, but nope - needed a lib.. Thank you so much!